# returning json from a separate file in react.js

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

trying to return json result to a component, trying to setup the json fetch in the separate file so i can reuse it.  but stuggling

index.js

```
export const getData = (data) => {

return fetch('http://localhost:9968/api/vehicle')
.then(response => response.json())
.then((data) => {
    return response.json()
})
```

carlist.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getData } from '../api';

export default
class CarList extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: null
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    getData((data) => {
        this.setState({
            data
        })
    });
}

render() {
    if(this.state.data) {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (
            <h1>Car list</h1>
        )
    }

    return (<h1>Loading...</h1>);
}
```

}

this is the json i expect to print to screen, in postman i know the end point works but react is not returning anything

```
{
    "vehicles": [
        {
            "id": "x",
            "modelYear": "98",
            "url": "/api/vehicle/tt",
            "media": [
                {
                    "name": "vehicle",
                    "url": "/images/1.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "z",
            "modelYear": "99",
            "url": "/api/vehicle/ff",
            "media": [
                {
                    "name": "vehicle",
                    "url": "/images/2.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },

    ]
   }
```

Comment: You pass a callback into `getData` in `componentDidMount` but you don't use it.

Comment: Hi, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function you are using returns promise which should return json response.So remove the response.json() only return response from promise.

```
export const getData = () => {
 return fetch('http://localhost:9968/api/vehicle')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((response) => {
   return response
})
```

Then use async and await for componentDidMount and also remove the data that you are passing to getData function.

```
async componentDidMount() {
let response = await getData();
this.setState({
  data: response
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getData` function returns `promise`.

In `CarList` component you can do this,

```
componentDidMount() {
    getData(data).then((data) => {
        this.setState({
            data
        })
    });
}
```

Also your `getData` function is a bit wrong, you are returning `response.json()` instead of `data`, you should directly return `data` like,

```
export const getData = (data) => {
   return fetch('http://localhost:9968/api/vehicle')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      return data  //instead of `response.json()` return data directly
    })
}
```

**Note:** You are passing `data` to `getData` function but not using it, pass the `data` only when you need it.

Comment: @user2286483, have you tried this, is this helpful? Is it working?